# Numpy: get only the array rows that have a value in an interval

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array which which has a shape of (10, 3) and looks like:

```
10 | xxx | yyy
11 | xxx | yyy
13 | xxx | yyy
14 | xxx | yyy
15 | xxx | yyy
17 | xxx | yyy
19 | xxx | yyy
..............
```

What I want is to extract only the rows which have the value of the first column between 12 and 16, for example. I tried with numpy.where(), but I didn't really manage to.

So what I want is something that returns:

```
13 | xxx | yyy
14 | xxx | yyy
15 | xxx | yyy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `filter` and `lambda`:

```
filtered_array = numpy.array(filter(lambda row: 12<row[0]<16, array))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
b = your_array[:,0]
condition = (b>12) & (b<16)

new_array = your_array[condition]
```